# Given value in livewire component mount doesn't be conserved, during others functions component function

Tags: laravel, variables, laravel-livewire, mount

I have iniitate $item variable in my livewire component, now during another function rotateItemsRight() which is triggered during a click on a button through wire:click, When I see the value of items it's empty
This is my  livewire component:

```
class Portfolio extends Component
{
    protected $main_item_id;
    protected $items=[];
    protected $rotationAngle = 0;
    protected $rotationDiff = 0;
    protected $rotates=[];
    protected $translateXs=[];
    protected $translateYs=[];

    public function mount(){
        $projects = Project::all();
        $this->main_item_id=0;
        $this->items=json_decode(json_encode($projects),true);
        $this->rotationAngle = 3*M_PI/2;
        $this->rotationDiff = 2*M_PI/count($this->items);
        $this->setTransform();
    }

    public function rotateItemsRight()
    {
        $this->rotationAngle += $this->rotationDiff;
        $this->main_item_id--;
        dd(count($this->items));
        $this->main_item_id%=count($this->items);
        $this->setTransform();
        
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        $items=$this->items;
        $main_item_id =$this->main_item_id;
        $rotationAngle =$this->rotationAngle;
        $rotationDiff =$this->rotationDiff;
        $rotates=$this->rotates;
        $translateXs=$this->translateXs;
        $translateYs=$this->translateYs;
        return view('livewire.portfolio',compact(['items','main_item_id','rotationAngle','rotationDiff','rotates','translateXs','translateYs']))->extends('layouts.app');
    }
}
```

This is my blade file:

```
<div class="option row">
                    <a class="btn my-2 col-1 left" wire:click="rotateItemsLeft"><small><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></small></a>
                        @if ($items[$main_item_id]['url'] !="#")
                        <a href="{{ $items[$main_item_id]['url'] }}" class="btn btn-primary col-4">Visit Project</a>
                        @endif
                        <a href="{{url('/projects/'.$items[$main_item_id]['id'])}}" class="btn btn-primary col-4">Project Details</a>
                    <a class="btn my-2 col-1 right" wire:click="rotateItemsRight"><small><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></small></a>
                </div>
```

How I make $items conserve his value assigned during mount?

Answer (score 2):

Livewire will only keep track of the state for `public` properties on the class. `protected` and `private` properties will not be rehydrated on subsequent requests.

This means that you'll have to change the properties you'll want to keep a state on, to `public` properties,

```php
public $items = [];
```

The same applies to all properties that are not static, or that you explicitly set during a `boot()` lifecycle-hook.

That will also result in the value being exposed in the frontend, so be wary to not put any sensitive information there.